# Remove escaped characters like new line, tabs, carriage returns, etc. inside a string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How can I remove escaped and escaped escaped newlines, tabs carriage returns, etc. ?

```
sentence = "\ndirty string \n \\n \\\\n \t\\t\\\\t \r\\r\\\\r"
```

A classic brute force approach is to do

```
" ".join(sentence.split())
```

but the escaped characters remain:

```
"dirty string \\n \\\\n \\t\\\\t \\r\\\\r"
```

how can I transform my string so that it will look like:

```
"dirty string"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While, for example, `\n` is an escape character, `\\n` is not. This is why you are left with strings like `\\n \\\\n \\t\\\\t \\r\\\\r` after `sentence.split()`.

This will return the desired output:

```
result=" ".join(word for word in sentence.split() if not word.startswith("\\"))
```

It breaks the sentence down into words, striping any leading or trailing whitespace, but only considering words that do not start with a backslash. Remember things like `\\n` are not escape characters but representation of literal string `\n`.

Btw I wouldn't call your attempt "brute force", as string functions like `split()`, `strip()`, `join()`, `replace()` etc. are intended for solving exactly this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex pattern such as `(\\n|\\r|\\t|\\)`

Input:

```
sentence = "\ndirty string \n \\n \\\\n \t\\t\\\\t \r\\r\\\\r"
```

Strip:

```
import re
x = re.sub(r"(\\n|\\r|\\t|\\)", "", sentence).strip()
```

Result:

```
'dirty string'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
sentence = "\ndirty string \n \\n \\\\n \t\\t\\\\t \r\\r\\\\r"\

print(''.join(s for s in sentence if (s.isalnum() or (s == ' '))))
# Output: dirty string  n n tt rr
```

On looking at your sentence, some of the letters have not been escaped. I've put brackets around the escaped characters that I can see:

```
"(\n)dirty string (\n) (\\)n (\\)(\\)n (\t)(\\)t(\\)(\\)t (\r)(\\)r(\\)(\\)r"
```

In this string literal, any characters outside the bracket have not been escaped, and you should consider whether you do want them to be thrown away.